# fetch from database in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im my script i want to read from ajax.php and show them and in my ajax.php i want to fetch from database . my problem is fetching from database doesnt work!

```
echo
               '<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($products)):?>
                <div class="item-in-cart clearfix">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="images/<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" width="124" height="124" alt="cart item" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="desc">
                            <strong>
                                <a href="product.html">s</a>
                            </strong>
                            <span class="light-clr qty">
                                <a href="#" class="icon-remove-sign" title="Remove Item"></a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="price">
                            <strong></strong>
                        </div>
                </div>';
                <?php endwhile;?>


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".addCart").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'ajax.php',
                data :{
                    id : 'id',
                },
                success : function (response) {
                $('#cart').html(response);
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work." Also why are you echoing PHP code to the browser?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen because i want to give me a response  and i cal it in ajax show them into my index page

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code.

Comment: @roberto06 would you tell me the correct syntax

Comment: You have to escape your quotes in `$row['id']` : `$row[\'id\']`. Also, your `endwhile` is out of your string, hence resulting in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the loop of return of your AJAX, put all the result in one concatenated string inside a variable. then echo that variable serve as return in ajax.

make sure that there is an tags with an ID "cart"

ajax.php

```
<?php
$return = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)):
$id = $row['id'];
$return .= "<div class='item-in-cart clearfix'>
    <div class='image'>
        <img src='images/$id' width='124' height='124' alt='cart item' />
    </div>
    <div class='desc'>
        <strong>
            <a href='product.html'>s</a>
        </strong>
        <span class='light-clr qty'>
            <a href='#' class='icon-remove-sign' title='Remove Item'></a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class='price'>
        <strong></strong>
    </div>
</div>";
endwhile;

echo $return;
?>
```

then the lump of HTML data will be push and insert inside the cart ID tags, but also upon calling the ajax, or before it get insert, empty the cart id first

```
$('#cart').html('');
$('#cart').html(response);
```